# How to best setup spfx on a new environment

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

I'm looking at setting up a spfx on a new environment and i'm looking for ways to automate/improve the installation  maybe using some generator or something similar.
Also some good resources and links to help debug issues faster and what commands needs to do what etc..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend these resources for setting up your development environment. They cover both Windows and macOS.

[How to Set up a SharePoint Framework Developer Environment for SharePoint Online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reGptSXsAk0)

[How to set up SPFx development environments for multiple SharePoint Server deployments](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/how-to-setup-sharepoint-framework-development-environment-for-multiple-sharepoint-server-deployments/)

Comment: Thanks Rob will have a look at the video